# "How to add left border for list when it is active?"

Tags: vue.js

How to add left border to the lists when they were active using css?

https://codepen.io/pen/?&editable=true&editors=101

```html
<v-list-group 
  v-for="item in items" 
  :key="item.title" 
  v-model="item.active" 
  :prepend-icon="item.action" 
  no-action>
  <template v-slot:activator>
    <v-list-tile>
      <v-list-tile-content>
        <v-list-tile-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-tile-title>
      </v-list-tile-content>
    </v-list-tile>
  </template>

  <v-list-tile 
    v-for="subItem in item.items" 
    :key="subItem.title" 
    @click="">
    <v-list-tile-content>
      <v-list-tile-title>{{ subItem.title }}</v-list-tile-title>
    </v-list-tile-content>

    <v-list-tile-action>
      <v-icon>{{ subItem.action }}</v-icon>
    </v-list-tile-action>
  </v-list-tile>
</v-list-group>
```

Comment: Your codepen is broken

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xNqzEw?&editable=true&editors=101

Comment: Here is the codepen

Comment: @dileepkumarreddylingampalli if you use ``` to format your code, don't post code in the same line as ``` - these lines will be invisible; you can also [edit] your question and fix the codepen link there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.v-list__group--active {
   border-left: 1px solid red
}
```

Comment: can we have this border to right when rtl property is enabled.

Comment: I thought you should use JS in such a situation.

Comment: when i use vuetify 2.0.0-beta.0 version this style is not working.